# "PYTHON: How can I connect a GitHub-hosted website on Google Cloud Platform to a local database server via VPN?"

Tags: python-3.x, database, google-cloud-platform

I'm kinda new to Cloud Hosting. I have a Python base code hosted in Github, this code is used to build a webpage that is hosted in Google Cloud platform. Nonetheless, I have a local server which hosts the database.

When I'm not in the office, I can connect to the local network with a VPN. I need to pull data but I don't know how to connect my webpage to the database. Due to security reasons we can't publish the local server (we don't want to expose it).

I also don't know the exact technical terms for asking this question, and I explained myself the best I could, I hope it is enough.

Please advise me in connecting to the database.

Thanks in advance for any response.

So what I want to do is basically:

User clicks in button -> webpage connects to database, pulls data, process data,etc -> download report

From the previous flow I know how to do everything except the webpage connection to the local database. In localhost this works 100% because I am connected to the same network than the server, but in deploy the server is not in the same network.

Comment: If it works in localhost, I guess that the web page is server generated (the modern way to do website is to have Javascript webpage that call API on a backend only for the data. The webpage are not generated on the fly). So, if it's your case, you must connect your webserver to the database through a VPN. Go to your VPC, create a VPN and enter the correct information. Do the same thing in your local network. But you must involve the network admin for that (IP range overlap, NAT, and stuff like that).